# Delete a column from all the tables that contains this column

Tags: mysql, sql, information-schema

This may be a naive question but I am new to SQL. There is a column 'X' that exists in multiple tables. I want to delete the COLUMN 'X' from all the tables that contain this column using a single query.

Comment: SImple answer - you can't.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with a single query but that might not matter because deleting a column is a one time operation so doing something like this might suffice:

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', table_name, ' DROP COLUMN ', column_name) 
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE column_name = 'x'
```

There's no schema info here; add it if you need. Running this query will give you a set of results that are the SQL you have to run to drop the columns. Columns that are part of a relationship/FK may not drop

If you want to write something eg a stored procedure that drops a column given as a named parameter, you'll have to build the results of an sql like this into a string and exec it dynamically; the programmatic equivalent of you running this query in your query tool, copying the results grid, pasting into the query editor and running the generated SQL

Answer (score 0):

Deleting column is not like selecting or deleting some rows from tables which can be done with one SQL.
For deleting the column from table, you need to write the alter statement and all tables will not have the same key constraints. 
If you are sure that there are no constraints then you can try using the Procedural SQL. But just SQL will not do it.